# iOS Where did my Title, Cancel and Save buttons go?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, navbar

I'm making some changes to my app, but as far as I can tell, they don't involve the NewActivityViewController. Now, the app launches, but my buttons and the title have disappeared from the Nav Bar.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

ScreenShot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't explain the problem, I resolved it by deleting the NavController then embedding the ViewController in a new NavController. Nothing else was required.

Many thanks @Aaron!

Answer (score 1):

Those items are described on your view controller's `navigationItem` property.  They will only appear if your view controller is displayed within a navigation controller.

In the screenshot you're showing, you are only displaying the view controller (child), you aren't displaying the navigation controller (parent).

Comment: It's just to the left of the sim in the screenshot. It was working before my changes (which affected only my HomeViewCOntroller), and I didn't do anything to disconnect it from the ViewController.